# Test Vectors for XEdDSA

Tags: signature, test-vectors

Anyone aware of test vectors (preferably with intermediate values) for the [XEdDSA algorithm](https://signal.org/docs/specifications/xeddsa/#xeddsa)?

Answer (score 2):

Open Whisper Systems' own `curve25519-java` repository [has a few test vectors in the code in `android/jni/ed25519/tests/`](https://github.com/signalapp/curve25519-java/tree/35658a7/android/jni/ed25519/tests). From `xeddsa_fast_test()`, you get this test vector in particular:

- Private key is all zeroes except byte 8, which is set to 189, and then clamped and the private key generated from there
- The message is 200 bytes of zeroes
- The random bytes are 64 bytes of zeroes
- The resulting signature of this should be the byte sequence 11c7f3e6c4df9e8a5150e1db3b30f92de3a3b3aa438656545fa7390f4bcc7bb26c431d9e90643e4f0eaa0e9c557766fa69ada576d63dcaf2ac326c11d0b97702.

---

Incidentally, XEdDSA as specified has been [found not to mitigate sufficiently well against differential power analysis](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/985.pdf). If the *only* reason why you're interested in XEdDSA is only mitigation of power-analysis attacks, you may want to look into the Internet Draft [draft-mattsson-cfrg-det-sigs-with-noise-02](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-mattsson-cfrg-det-sigs-with-noise-02) instead, which took into account the aforementioned findings.